# Google material chart strange border when converting to pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-api, wkhtmltopdf

I used the google js api to create a material chart as in the following capture

[image]

As you can see, there is a black border that I do not want there. This is however only when I convert the html page to a pdf using wkhtlmtopdf.
Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: You mean the line on the left and bottom? That is probably the shadow of the container (card?).  Try to set it's elevation to 0, that's should result in no shadow.

Comment: it's a border, it is also on top and right but I did not include it in the capture